# Draggable button bar in jquery-wysiwym editor

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jwysiwyg

I am trying to build [a markdown editor](http://editortest.comule.com/) learning from [this tutorial](http://pushingkarma.com/projects/jquery-wysiwym/). Mostly, I just tweaked some CSS only.

I tried to make the button panel draggable using [this blog post](http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/02/ultra-small-code-to-drag-everything-in.html). But upon adding that code, the editor stopped working.

In the head (after all the js files):

```
$(function() {  
      $('#pad').wysiwym(Wysiwym.Markdown,{ helpEnabled: true, helpToggle: true });
       $('#draggables div').each(function(drag){new Drag.Move(drag);});
});
```

And in the body section:

```
<div id='draggables'>
<textarea id = 'pad' wrap="off" >
</textarea>
</div>
```

Textarea is converted into the `Wysiwym.Markdown` editor. After conversion buttons are added in a `div` on top of the `textarea`. As per the blog, that `div` should have been movable. but instead, the plugin stopped working, i.e. the `textarea` is not converted into editor.

Basic idea is to make the button bar movable so that user can use it as per their convenience. [Something like on the home screen of aloha-editor.](http://aloha-editor.org/) The panel is movable but the `textarea` is fixed. Why wasn't it working?

Comment: I did it myself. used standard `JQuery-ui draggable function` on the div. found out the divs id via firebug. and added css `position:fixed` to make it even better